# Prevent Typescript narrowing in conditional branch

Tags: typescript

It seems like Typescript is narrowing a union when doing control flow analysis:

```typescript
type Foo = {x: number}
type Bar = {x: number, y: string}


function f(arg: Foo | Bar) {

    // Type of a is Foo | null
    const a = true ? arg : null
}
```

I assume the type of `a` is `Foo | null` because `Foo` is a subtype of `Bar` and so is the minimal safe type here. How do I prevent this narrowing from happening? For example, what if I wanted to do the following:

```typescript
function p(arr: (Foo | Bar)[]) {

    const b = arr.length ? arr[0] : null;

    // Treat b as Foo | Bar | null
    if (b && 'y' in b) {
        
        // Error: Property 'y' does not exist on type 'never'
        console.log(b.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code really doesn't make any sense, particularly the weird ternary assignment. Taking an element from an empty array already returns undefined, and [doesn't confuse the compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAHgLigOwK4C2ARhAE4C+AUKJFAEICGpyaWuhJpANFCNgM7BSASxwBzKpQBmeHAGNgwuDihgAFE1LY18RAB96TAJQBtALpG0lSlFtQ5ywVCItNJgAxmA3NbtQA9P5QACqkEAzAzlAM-LAIUAaMzAb4ADapNnbCUlBqLgBk+VAA5CDFUKLOlqiZfra1dYFQAKKkpHBaUAAK7ZCkoCVlUAAmcBCxOHCREOjCTspQNNDFOBAAbmTFDX4OOPxwqRAAdKlwYnlHIEY+flRUtkA). It also gets the type correct if you do e.g. `const b = arr[0] || null;`.

Comment: @JaredSmith Not sure what's weird about the ternary assignment. I'm checking to make sure the array isn't empty (effectively `arr.length !== 0`) and then taking the first element for further use.

Comment: Why? Again, you can take an element from an empty array, so the check isn't really necessary. The idiom you're using isn't very common, and it seems to be confusing the compiler over the simpler alternatives. Also just to clarify, I just think it's 'weird', not necessarily 'wrong'.

Comment: @JaredSmith One problem with your example is the type system has no concept of out-of-bounds array access so the type of `arr[0]` is `Foo | Bar` instead of `Foo | Bar | undefined`. You lose that type information and using `b` later on without checking for `undefined` would throw at runtime. In my example, Typescript would require you to handle the null case explicitly.

Comment: Odd, disjoint types preserve the union (try removing `x` from `Bar`). I bet this is a bug. In the meantime, you could of course just manually annotate `a` and `b` with `Foo | Bar | null` since the inferred `Foo | null` is a subtype.

Comment: @arseneyr the word "intersection" in "narrowing a union to its intersection" is  problematic.  `Foo` is not the intersection of `Foo` and `Bar`; it's the union.  You can say the *properties* of `Foo | Bar` become the intersection of the *properties* of `Foo` and `Bar`, but that's true of all non-discriminated unions.

Comment: Browsing the typescript github issues a bit, this appears to be a case of "subtype reduction" which is done on [all?] inferred types. See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39550#issuecomment-659196501) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35690#issuecomment-566320325). So you may really have to annotate explicitly.

Comment: Yes, this is subtype reduction (sound but sometimes annoying) playing not-nicely with the `in` type guard (useful but unsound).  It's not really a bug so much as a design limitation.  There's an issue [microsoft/TypeScript#37518](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37518) which seems to be exactly this but it's just "needs investigation".  The right thing to do here is to prevent subtype reduction by making the union disjoint or even not a union.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since every `Bar` is also a `Foo`, the union `Foo | Bar` is equivalent to just `Foo`, in terms of which values can be assigned to them.  In some sense, `Foo | Bar` contains no more information than just `Foo`, much like `string | "hello"` contains the same information as just `string`.

When the compiler explicitly converts `Foo | Bar` to `Foo`, this is called "subtype reduction" (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#4537](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4537)).  This is *sound* but sometimes annoying because while technically the `| Bar` doesn't give you any more information about what types of values might be there, pragmatically speaking it gives you a hint that maybe the `y` property can be used to determine what it is.

---

The [`in` operator is treated as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#15256](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256)) where the presence of a property is used to narrow a union type.  This is *useful* but unsound.  Pragmatically speaking, you expect that if an `{a: 0} | {b: 1}` contains an `a` property then it's an `{a: 0}`, but technically speaking you can't assume that.  After all, the value `{a: "oops", b: 1}` is a valid `{a: 0} | {b: 1}` but *not* a valid `{a: 0}`.  The mere presence of an `a` property does not technically tell you enough to narrow the type, but pragmatically it does.

---

These two ways of treating properties and unions are at odds with each other, and in a case like yours they interact poorly.

First `Foo | Bar` gets reduced to `Foo` (technically correct), which is not known to have a `y` property.  Then you use the `in` operator to check for a `y` property, which decides that it cannot be a `Foo` at all due to its lack of a known `y` property (technically incorrect).

There's an issue [microsoft/TypeScript#37518](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37518) which seems to be exactly this but it's just marked as "needs investigation".  I'm pretty sure that this is just a design limitation and not a bug, per se.  Each feature is working as advertised.

---

So what can be done?  There are a few approaches.  One way is to change the element type of `arr` from `Foo | Bar` to either a disjoint union or a non-union type, like either of these:

```
type FooNotBar = { x: number, y?: never };
function q(arr: (FooNotBar | Bar)[]) {
    const b = arr.length ? arr[0] : null;
    if (b && typeof b.y !== "undefined") {
        console.log(b.y.toUpperCase()); // okay
    }
}

type FooOrBar = { x: number, y?: string };
function r(arr: (FooOrBar)[]) {
    const b = arr.length ? arr[0] : null;
    if (b && typeof b.y !== "undefined") {
        console.log(b.y.toUpperCase()); // okay
    }
}
```

Here, `FooNotBar` is a `Foo` which is *not* a `Bar` because it cannot have a defined `y` property.  So `FooNotBar | Bar` can use the `y` property to determine which type it is.  Equivalently, `FooOrBar` is a `Foo` which is either a `Bar` or a non-`Bar` because `y` will either be a `string` or it will not be defined.  Again, you can check the `y` property to determine which.  Note that neither of those work with the `in` type guard, though, since it no longer can use the mere presence of the `y` key to determine which type you have.

---

Another approach is to keep your `Foo | Bar` and let it be collapsed to `Foo` by the compiler, but to use a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to give your own desired behavior instead of the default `in` type guard behavior:

```
const isBar = (x: Foo): x is Bar => 'y' in x;

function s(arr: (Foo | Bar)[]) {
    const b = arr.length ? arr[0] : null;
    if (b && isBar(b)) {
        console.log(b.y.toUpperCase()); // okay
    }
}
```

Here you are saying "if I call `isBar(foo)`, a `true` result means that `foo` can be treated like a `Bar`".  The *implementation* of `isBar()` just uses `in`, but the *signature* of `isBar()` communicates the intent.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAPAXFAdgVwFsAjCAJygF8AoUSKAIQEMKV1s8jSyAaKEHAGdgZAJa4A5lWrUAZvlwBjYKLi4osgBQsJOeIgA+jFgEo01KJagB6a1AAq4aHFlQmUUYNgIoRggBt-CytFNWE3ZCgRfGgAfjcyKRwAoJo5BWVVdTBtMjIcTX1fYzITAG0AXTNUYMtQ3HDiSJYyADp-CElgAAsoeJaygAYKqGT8QIBuWps7ezIIJmAoJqYvIqNmCj9xoKsPV00mgDIjqAByEDOPdWJq6b3bKABRPLh8qAAFMjhIMlBzy5QAAmcAgXlwcCWEAwniWaiiTnOuAgADdyGd7iEwnAOu04BJDq0QCYpnsaGk6NB9AA5SGbSLsMYkch8ECxZKo8hUKbyJQqeEAR1y70KCFpwHpG1MlTue3qjWaeXanQkPT6CTIQxGY0m01EB2Op0pLmWRKgAEIkCgAEQKIEQWTiCBA62yvZYho4iB4gnEImtYBwACqYF+AGFVhBNCYSTMoHAANZMEDTckySneOAAeTI9LYmCZ3FZ7KgwjEkm56T5WSgZGFBX0Oc25Sq5jlYSWTRQLWVXV6-TyWtGnF1e31UEOUBOCMgJr9IAtVqgttw9sdyJd1SgmLq2Nx-nxhJAAeDofIEcEUZjEzjieTqeoaXlS08eYnHH0JhwGA8XjzAD4ASucRMCmKtMnhQR6wndYShbN1dwaTtFTaDo+3VAZhmHFJSSscdJ2nV8WEOGM23dRDBC9H0jxPENw0jaNY0eO8UzJR9qCAA)